# Recursive version of python unittest assertDictContainsSubset

Tags: python, unit-testing

[Python unittest's assertDictContainsSubset recommended alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20050913/python-unittests-assertdictcontainssubset-recommended-alternative) discusses how to check if a `dict` contains another `dict` using `d1 | d2`.  However, that seems to only work at the top level.

If I have

```
d1 = {
   'a': 1
   'b': {
      'c': 2
      'd': 3
   }
}

d2 = {
   'b': {
      'c': 2
   }
}
```

and I want to check if `d1` contains everything in `d2`, I cannot do `assertEquals(d1, d1 | d2)`.  The union will ignore the `a` field at the top level of `d1`, but it fails because `d` is not in the nested `dict`.

I could write code that loops over `d1.items` and recurses if the value is a dict, but that starts to get awkward (especially since it would also have to handle tuples and lists in the general case).

Is there something that already exists that handles this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a pre-existing tool for this, but I took a shot at writing a recursive function:

```
def subdict(d, d0):
    """
    return true if d0 items are a subset of d items, recursively
    """
    for k0, v0 in d0.items():
        if k0 not in d:
            return False
        v = d[k0]
        if isinstance(v, dict) and isinstance(v0, dict):
            if not subdict(v, v0):
                return False
        elif v != v0:
            return False
    return True
```